# What is the difference semantically between речь and выступление?

Tags: перевод

I believe both речь and выступление can have the same shade of meaning that the word "speech" does in English (not as in an utterance, but as in a formal address you give before an audience). I was curious as to what the actual difference between these words is in Russian. Is there a difference in formality? Does one imply something the other doesn't? Any insights on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*Речь* means "speech" (in every sense of the word).

*Выступление* means "performance (in front of audience)", more often than not as a standalone act (as opposed to playing a part in a larger play or show).

*Речь* is not necessarily done in front of an audience, and *выступление* is not necessarily giving a speech.

*Выступление оперной певицы на сцене Большого* means "The opera diva's performance on the Bolshoi stage" (even though she was singing and not giving a speech).

The Russian for "to give a speech" would be *выступить с речью*, literally "to perform with a speech".

Semantically, *выступать* is close to German *auftreten* (from *auf-* "on, upon" and *treten* "to step"). I don't know if it's a calque or if it developed in the two languages independently of each other.

Comment: I've often wondered this myself. What an excellent response!

Comment: This is a great response with a lot of details! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Я не знаю, что там семантика врёт, но с точки зрения этимологии:

*речь* - это процесс осмысленного говорения слов или фраз человеком (у животных речи нет), осознанное пользование языком (не путать с сознательным использованием языка), скорее всего связано со словом риторика (ῥητορική), скорее всего связано с немецким sprechen и происходит от общего праиндоевропейского корня([*(s)prei-](https://etymologeek.com/deu/sprechen#:%7E:text=Proto%2DIndo%2DEuropean-,*(s)prei%2D,-%2C%20Proto%2DIndo%2DEuropean)), но скорее всего оно ближе к другому слову - *rede/reden*, говорить осмысленно(*см. внизу), возможно, [связано со словом река](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0#:%7E:text=%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%90%20%D0%B6.%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%3F)),

> Тогда речь - это процесс "истечение мыслей, по средствам языка"(the
> ideas flowing out of one's mind by the wording).

Связано со словом перечить - говорить обратное, высказывать противоположные идеи, спорить.

> *Речь — это достояние только человека, животные не говорят, а издают звуки.* К. Платонов, Занимательная психология.

А вы-**ступ**-ление - от *ступ*, выдаваться/выходить(выступ/выступать), при шагании/ходьбе(ступать), нижняя часть ноги являющаяся основой для ходьбы(ступня) - то, чем соприкасаешься с землей при ходьбе. Ступ~step. *Выступать* - тут, дословно, выходить на сцену, подниматься на сцену (для чего?). *Выступать* на сцене можно и без произнесения речи - играть роли в спектакле, ("выступает чемпион прошлого сезона.."), играть любой артистический номер, ("на арене цирка выступают акробаты!"). *Выступают* обычно говорят, когда объявляют номер или того, кто будет выступать: "выступает известный артист театра и балета..." *Выступать* говорят о выдвижении ~ move on. Также *выступать* - "ходить, идти чинно, важной поступью," - возможно, связано со сходством приставки ВЫ со вторым лицом множественным числом ВЫ, которое используется при обращении к вышестоящему ~ You+step

> То есть разница в том, на какое слово делается акцент, потому что
> полностью фразеологизм звучит ***выступать с речью*** (а не с цирковым
> или музыкальным номером) - но в какую сторону *обрубаем* фразу? если в
> сторону глагола - то остается ***выступать***, а если в сторону "...с
> речью" - то ***речь***.

The distinctions between **speech** and **речь**:

Speech mainly is about specific functions of the sounds creating while talking. Especially by the usage [the tongue directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech#:%7E:text=The%20human%20species%27%20unprecedented%20use%20of%20the%20tongue%2C%20lips%20and%20other%20moveable%20parts%20seems%20to%20place%20speech%20in%20a%20quite%20separate%20category%2C%20making%20its%20evolutionary%20emergence%20an%20intriguing%20theoretical%20challenge%20in%20the%20eyes%20of%20many%20scholars.).

А если взять способ общения глухонемых - [жестовую речь](https://studopedia.ru/2_26263_zhestovaya-rech-osobennosti-zhestovogo-yazika-gluhih.html#:%7E:text=%D0%96%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C.%20%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%85), то в английском варианте - это [not a speech, but a language - Sign languages (also known as signed languages) are languages that use the visual-manual modality to convey meaning, instead of spoken words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_language#:%7E:text=that%20use%20the%20visual%2Dmanual%20modality%20to%20convey%20meaning%2C%20instead%20of%20spoken%20words.).

Но *речь* более широкое понятие, так же как и *язык* (a toung and a language both meaning, wording). *Речь* в свою очередь - это и вербальное произнесение слов по средствам языка, но и невербальная - [внутренняя речь или мысленная речь](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-inner-speech-1691070) (~self-talk, not inner dialogue -all of that in wiki calles "[interpersonal communication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrapersonal_communication)"). Внутренняя речь - то что существует до языка и/или без языка. Также ***речь* не имеет прямого значения слова *communication*, но может выступать необходимым условием для коммуникации**. Внутренняя речь - это чисто русских подход к пониманию и изучению мышления и разума человека, как видите википедия идет путем коммуникации - передачи сигналов, в то время как речь существует без обмена "сигналами", внутренняя речь существует не за счет сознания и сознательной деятельности, а за счет **осознания** - доведение чего-либо до понимания, до собственного сознания, разумение, формирования собственного разума(~self minding), а не воздействие на сознание "другого" через слова и их значение. Сказать *речь* - чаще всего будет значить произнести монолог. В то время как *speech* - это диалог.

В немецком есть еще одно слово, которое часто имеет значение "говорить" - rede/reden. Так вот [*немецкие попугаи*](https://angelikasgerman.co.uk/what-is-the-difference-between-reden-sprechen-sagen/#:%7E:text=A%20German%20parrot%20speaks%20whereas%20an%20English%20parrot%20talks%20%E2%80%93%20%C2%A0must%20be%20because%20%C2%A0a%20German%20parrot%20just%C2%A0speaks%20random%20words%20without%20having%20a%20real%20conversation%20and%20an%20English%20parrot%20just%20talks%20a%20lot%20of%20rubbish) не обладают речью-rede, они только озвучивают слова, а не произносят их осмысленно. *Rede*, в отличие от *sprechen*, также имеет значение *выступать с речью*/*произносить речь* - *eine Rede halten*. Более подробно о разнице между sprechen and reden можно почитать [тут](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-reden-und-sprechen#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9EReden%E2%80%9C%20bezieht%20sich%20auf%20den%20sozialen%20Akt%2C%20der%20mit%20Sprache%20vollzogen%20wird%3A%20Man%20redet%20mit%20oder%20zu%20jemandem%20und%20%C3%BCber%20etwas%2C%20um%20Information%20auszutauschen%2C%20Beziehungen%20zu%20pflegen%2C%20Macht%20auszu%C3%BCben%20usw.%20%E2%80%9EReden%E2%80%9C%20ist%20eine%20Handlung%20im%20sozialen%20Kontext.).

Если проводить параллель с английским, то скорее всего речь-rede ближе к слову read - to read the text by verbal speaking, or to read memories, thoughts, minding by non-verbal.

Comment: Спасибо вам за этимологическую информацию!

Comment: @johnna_nyet: I think I should mention that the etymological connection between Russian _речь_, Greek _ῥητορική_, German _sprechen_, and Russian _река_ is either made up by the author of this post, or blindly copied from a parascientific source. The etymologies of all these words are readily available both online and offline, and no reputable source supports their connection.

Comment: @Quassnoi "РЕКА ж. (от реять, течь, общего корня с речь?)" - Даль, Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка. Хотелось бы услышать ваши аргументы по поводу речь=спич. Хотя.. не хотелось бы. До свидания.

Comment: @Quassnoi - всё, добавил ссылки, и можете спорить с Далем и с логикой немецкого языка в том числе. Вам как лингвисту/филологу стыдно путать речь с говорением.

Comment: @CocoPop "Речь - это в основном специфические функции звуков, создаваемых во время речи..." = "А - это B, существующее при наличие А" - логическая чепуха, то что вы напереводили.

Comment: @Quassnoi it wasn't necessarily relevant to my question anyways, since my question was about practical semantics and use in sentences, so I didn't double check this. Thank you!

Comment: @johnna_nyet etymology > semantic, mister quassnoi had not get any proof to his text, that i did, if you need to check, you can follow the links. Semantical речь is more close to read, but not same,. And речь not ever = speech. Speech - это говорение, разговорный процесс. but it goes closer probably in сказать речь = read(download) the speech, where речь is read, and сказать is the speech - is can be translated (an act of) речевого высказывания.  Наречь/нарекать verb - to give a (vor)"name" to the thin or entity. But наречь is not same as to nominate and ofc not ever same with verb speech.